bazel grpc integration fails with ': error: 'PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_OPEN' does not name a type'
I am following simple steps enlisted here to incorporate gRPC (v1.64.1) in my bazel (v7.1.0) workspace on Linux. I am using a Linux docker container (ubuntu:focal) as the build environment. My workspace file follows the step as advertised and I have ported the helloworld application in my repo (I am calling it greeter).
When I build the greeter (helloworld) I get following error:
$ bazel build //utils/greeter:greeter_client
INFO: Analyzed target //utils/greeter:greeter_client (2 packages loaded, 135 targets configured).
. . .
Use --sandbox_debug to see verbose messages from the sandbox and retain the sandbox build root for debugging
In file included from bazel-out/aarch64-opt-exec-ST-13d3ddad9198/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/util/_virtual_includes/time_util/google/protobuf/util/time_util.h:30,
                 from external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/util/time_util.cc:8:
bazel-out/aarch64-opt-exec-ST-13d3ddad9198/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/_virtual_includes/duration_proto/google/protobuf/duration.pb.h:36:1: error: 'PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_OPEN' does not name a type
   36 | PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_OPEN
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
bazel-out/aarch64-opt-exec-ST-13d3ddad9198/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/_virtual_includes/duration_proto/google/protobuf/duration.pb.h:40:1: error: 'PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_CLOSE' does not name a type
   40 | PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_CLOSE
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

<s n i p>

external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/util/time_util.cc:117:13: warning: 'std::string google::protobuf::util::{anonymous}::FormatTime(int64_t, int32_t)' defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
  117 | std::string FormatTime(int64_t seconds, int32_t nanos) {
      |             ^~~~~~~~~~
Target //utils/greeter:greeter_client failed to build
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
INFO: Elapsed time: 7.331s, Critical Path: 5.17s
INFO: 14 processes: 11 internal, 3 linux-sandbox.
ERROR: Build did NOT complete successfully

It seems that gRPC (v1.64.1) has dependency on protobuf (v26.1) which it is trying to build without success. I am not sure if this is a build environment issue. The docker container provides a confined environment which maybe lacking some dependencies. I doubt there's anything existing in the build environment that maybe conflicting with protobuf build. Any ideas?
